# ansible_wait_for a file containing a name pattern

Tags: ansible

How can I use ansible wait_for module and search regex to wait for a file containing a certain naming format. For instance, a file can have the number within its name change from time to time as in "waitfor1234.txt" or "waitfor5678.txt". I would like to know how I can implement a solution like "waitfor*.txt" in ansible wait_for module. Thanks

```
#Below code doesn't work
name: Wait for file matching waitfor*.txt is present 
  wait_for:
    path: /tmp/foo/waitfor*.txt
```

Comment: See [search_regex](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/wait_for_module.html#parameter-search_regex). If you have a problem [edit] the question and make it [mre].

Comment: You should consider banning "It's not working" from your vocabulary on Q&A sites like SO, at least when used on its own. [It does not accurately describe your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/). You have an egg-chicken problem. `find` needs a specific filename. If you don't know the filename beforehand, you could look for it, e.g.use the `find` module to find results based on a pattern and loop on the result with `wait_for`. But you can only find existing files. In other words you cannot check a file will be created (and contain a regex) if you don't know its name.